# Having trouble placing inline JS into external JS and getting the same result

Tags: javascript, html, css, preload

I am trying to create a gif preloader for a project I have. In the course previous to the current one, we were allowed to place JS inline, like so:

```
<script>
    let loader = document.getElementById("loader");

    window.addEventListener("load", function () {
        loader.style.height = "400px";
        loader.style.width = "400px";
        loader.style.borderRadius = "50%";
        loader.style.visibility = "hidden";
    });

</script>
```

This ran with the following HTML and CSS:

```
HTML

<div id="loader">
    <img src="images/pepper.gif" alt="loading animation"/>
</div>

CSS

#loader {
    height: 2000px;
    width: 2000px;
    background-color: black;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    z-index: 999;
    transition: all .5s;
}

#loader img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

This worked just fine. However, in this course, it is requested that we place our JS in an external file.

I have linked the file like this

```
<script src="js/index.js"></script>
```

in the head tag of the HTML.

The JS looks like this (we are required to use IIFE):

```
(function () {

    "use strict";

    let loader = document.getElementById("loader");

    window.addEventListener("load", function () {
        loader.style.height = "400px";
        loader.style.width = "400px";
        loader.style.borderRadius = "50%";
        loader.style.visibility = "hidden";
    });
})();
```

My problem is, now, the gif will stay on the screen forever when in an external file. When it was inline, it would load for a bit and then display the contents of the site. Could anyone help me fix this?

Comment: Your script needs to be run when the document is ready You need an event handler to tirigger the script execution

Comment: If your JS is in the `<head>`, `document.getElementById("loader")` will be `null` because you don't wait for the DOM to be ready, so it does not exist yet _(open your browser's developer console with `F12` to see the errors it generates)_. Either put your script right before the closing `</body>` tag, or wrap your code with `addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() { /* code */ });`

Comment: hey @blex, thanks! you answered my question. can you please put your comment as an answer so I can mark it as the right one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your JS is in the `<head>` part, `document.getElementById("loader")` will be `null` because you don't wait for the DOM to be ready, so it does not exist yet. If you open your browser's developer console with <kbd>F12</kbd>, you'll see:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null

Either put your script right before the closing `</body>` tag, or wrap your code with:

```
addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() { /* code */ });
```